# How to fix ListView automatically sroll up in flutter

Tags: flutter

how can i fix automatic scroll up in ListView?
when i scroll down to get new data from grapql-server and update listView, scroll pops up to top.
I tried some method like jumpto, animate but it's same.
here is my entire code. please help me...

```
class _PostsScreenState extends State<PostsScreen> {
  int postsPerPage = 5;
  int currentPostCount = 0;

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> allPosts = [];

  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  FetchMore? _fetchMore;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController.addListener(_onScroll);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onScroll() {
    if (_fetchMore == null) return;

    if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
        _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
      final FetchMoreOptions fetchMoreOpts = FetchMoreOptions(
        variables: {'offset': allPosts.length},
        updateQuery: (previousResultData, fetchMoreResultData) {
          final List<dynamic> fetchedPosts = fetchMoreResultData?['viewPosts'];
          final List<Map<String, dynamic>> updatedPosts = List.from(allPosts)
            ..addAll(fetchedPosts.map((post) => post as Map<String, dynamic>));
          fetchMoreResultData?['viewPosts'] = updatedPosts;
          allPosts = updatedPosts;
          return fetchMoreResultData;
        },
      );

      _fetchMore!(fetchMoreOpts);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Query(
        options: QueryOptions(
          document: viewPostsQuery,
          variables: {
            "categoryId": widget.categoryId,
            "take": postsPerPage,
            "offset": currentPostCount,
          },
        ),
        builder: (QueryResult result,
            {VoidCallback? refetch, FetchMore? fetchMore}) {
          if (result.isLoading && allPosts.isEmpty) {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }

          if (result.data != null && _fetchMore != null) {
            final posts = result.data!['viewPosts'] as List<dynamic>?;
            allPosts =
                posts!.map((post) => post as Map<String, dynamic>).toList();

            _fetchMore = fetchMore;
          }

          _fetchMore = fetchMore;

          return _buildListView();
        });
  }

  Widget _buildListView() {
    return ListView.builder(
      controller: _scrollController,
      itemCount: allPosts.length,
      itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
        final post = allPosts[index];
        print(post['images']);
        return Post(post: post);
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

i tried to insert jump to method and animate method, it has same problem and i also tried to extract query widget

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you are trying to implement infinite pagination: as user scrolls new data is fetched and added to the overall list. For this use case, I would recommend [infinite_scroll_pagination](https://pub.dev/packages/infinite_scroll_pagination) package that makes this simple. Checkout this and feel free to ask any follow up questions if you struggle to implement or faced some errors.

Comment: It works same. I change LIstView to PagedListView but when get more data, scroll goes to the top.